# fmt.Printf not executing inside loop

Tags: go

I'm writing a small program in Go to check a server's status is up (out of a list of servers) by hostname. I have a function that iterates over a server type once they're all retrieved and stored from an http.GET into slice of type server.

I can log (commented out below) and see that both of these evaluate correctly:

```
// fmt.Printf("Server: %s - Status: %s\n", server.Name, status)
// fmt.Printf("%t\n", name == strings.ToLower(server.Name))
```

Both have the expected outcome but when I run the program, the `fmt.Printf()` call inside the if statement does not print to the console.

```
    func getServerStatus(name string) {
      servers := getAllServers()
      for _, server := range servers {
        status := boolToStatusString(server.Status)
        // fmt.Printf("Server: %s - Status: %s\n", server.Name, status)
        // fmt.Printf("%t\n", name == strings.ToLower(server.Name))
        if server.Name == strings.ToLower(name) {
          fmt.Printf("%s is %s", name, status)
        }
      }
    }
```

I've tried running this function as a `goroutine` with a `channel` of type `string` to store the result and call the `Printf` outside this function but anytime I `go run main.go` it just executes and prints nothing.

Solved: evaluating both as strings.ToLower in the if statement resolved the issue.

Comment: Does your program wait till the go routines finish?

Comment: Could you post how are you calling the function - getServerStatus ?

Comment: For example this program doesn't wait for the go routine therefore you don't see nothing: https://play.golang.org/p/qKFq15T19oV

Comment: I experimented with a goroutine for this but the outcome was the same.

It shouldn't require concurrent execution AFAIK since the http.Get is completed before the call.

Comment: Are you shure that your statment turned `true`?

Comment: @MikhailKatrin yes, it evaluates correctly

Comment: Your if condition is false. Please show the output with the prinfs uncommented (but just print `server.Name` and `name`). Also add an `else` with a print, and finally a printf after the if block.

Comment: Don't switch the ToLower conversion arbitrarily https://play.golang.org/p/PzbhvXce-Gh

Comment: @mkopriva that was it! wasn't downcasing both instances (`server.Name` and `name`)

/facepalm

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the evaluation was incorrect as I was not using `strings.ToLower()` on both causing the statement to always be false as the data was not sanitized before hand or at execution.

Credit to @mkopriva